# How do I tell an Eclipse plugin where a native library resides for an external plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I have an Eclipse plugin that is a Java wrapper for a C++ library. I'm running on Linux so the wrapper provides a .jar and a .so. I've created a plugin project from this latter existing JAR archive. I have pointed to the .so in the native library location for the jar.

I have another plugin that references this wrapper plugin. I can successfully run a standalone java application from this other plugin that utilizes the wrapper plugin successfully. The class that uses it has to import the java class from the wrapper jar and, before instantiating anything from the wrapper library, I have to call System.loadLibrary. This means I've set the native library location correctly, et cetera.

When I try to do the same kind of operation but within an OSGi context using a product definition, I get a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError. If I edit the run configuration for the product definition to add `-Djava.library.path=<full path to the .so>`, I am again able to run -- i.e., the library functions properly.

How do I add this path to the plugin configuration? Do I have to create a ClassLoader from my BundleContext inside of my Activator class or is there a plugin configuration way to do this?

I thought I had the right thing by add the path to the .so to the Runtime Classpath in the MANIFEST.MF of my wrapper plugin but that doesn't appear to do it -- I guess it is just for the classpath -- not the library path. Imagine that.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is not clear if you're using the Bundle-NativeCode header from the OSGi specification? This should not require you to set any env. paths.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do something similar in my project.

In my plugin that depends on native code, I have a folder named os at the root of the plugin, with the following contents:

```
os
-linux
 -x86
  -<libname>.so
-win32
 -x86
  -<libname>.dll
 -x86_64
  -<libname>.dll
```

the build.properties specifies (among other things) that the os folder should be packaged as part of the plugin build process:

```
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               plugin.xml,\
               lib/,\
               os/,\
               .,\
               schema/
```

When the product using the plugin runs under one of the platforms for which there is a provided native library, the Java `System.loadLibrary("libname")` call will resolve the library properly.

This is all being used successfully in my Eclipse 3.6.2 based RCP application.  However, I can't find any references that lay out this approach, so I wonder if it's being retired in favor of a more OSGi-friendly approach, using the Bundle-NativeCode directive, which I found several references to:

- [Eclipse Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Plug-in_Development_FAQ#How_do_I_include_native_libraries_in_my_bundle.3F)
- [Vogella blog post](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2010/07/27/osgi/)
- [Blog post](http://holistictendencies.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/bundle-nativecode-using-platform-specific-dlls-from-osgi/)

Comment: bin.includes was already set as you suggested. I also tried adding the Bundle-NativeCode directive to my wrapper plugin MANIFEST.MF. Neither of these worked. What does work (and this perplexes) is adding (without the Bundle directive) -Djava.library.path=lib/ to the plugin that is using the wrapper! Why? There is no lib/ directory in my plugin, but there is in the wrapper plugin. Why would setting the library path, in the plugin that uses the wrapper, with the relative path for the wrapper work? Nevertheless, the solution meets the portability need. An explanation would be nice, however.

Comment: are the native libraries in a folder structure that matches what I laid out though?  The OS and Architecture labels have to match.

Comment: My understanding is that RCP effectively adds a -Djava.library.path directive to the <pluginroot>/os/<OS>/<ARCH> directory, for whatever OS and ARCH the product is running in.  The bin.includes directive just makes sure the os directory gets included in the compiled plugin, it does not itself tell RCP/OSGi anything about it's contents.

Comment: Regarding how I'm using it, I have plugin A containing the native code and some Java code.  The Java code in plugin A is the ONLY Java code to access that native library.

Comment: I hadn't originally understood that I would need to set up my directories according to the structure you outlined, just that the directories with the .so are in build.includes. It seems to me that in addition to what you've laid out, you would have to still add Bundle-NativeCode for this to even possibly work. I tried your suggestion without this directive and with this directive and still no luck. Are you doing this with one plugin using a class from a different plugin that contains the native library?

Comment: I moved the above comment so I could edit it -- it was badly malformed but should be the third comment in sequence, before sharakan's two comments before this one.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I haven't had to do what you describe to get this to work in a self-contained plugin. The one case where I know I did what you're describing, I had the .so files at the root level. From other info I've seen on the web, this may simplify the problem. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I have quiet the same issue but I am not able to get it run this way. My libraries are set for `bin.includes` but the `.dll`-files do not show up after Eclipse started. If you'd take a look at my post this would be great! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697741/eclipse-plug-in-native-and-unnative-dependencies-management

Comment: Layout is defined here in code: https://github.com/eclipse/rt.equinox.framework/blob/bf2dced9a01e1516ee0c44dcc37d855ba1b41811/bundles/org.eclipse.osgi/container/src/org/eclipse/osgi/internal/framework/EquinoxConfiguration.java#L602

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your library is located file is located at /path/to/your/library/foobar.so

Have you tried this?

```
cd /path/to/eclipse
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/library:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./eclipse
```

The `-Djava.library.path` property should not include the `foobar.so` (as per LD_LIBRARY_PATH)

Examples:

```
-Djava.library.path=/path/to/your/library             #correct
-Djava.library.path=/path/to/your/library/foobar.so   #wrong

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/library:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH             #correct
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/library/foobar.so:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH   #wrong
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have already gone down this path. It works, but doesn't allow me to set the plugin up so that it will work out of the box.