# Eclipse: Setting an environment variable that references a folder contained in a plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have some Java code that wraps an existing native application and performs the following:

1. Takes some input from the user
2. Executes a native application providing as parameters the input taken in step 1
3. Performs some more operations on the output files produced in step 2

The native application in step 2 requires some dynamic libraries. So, under Run Configurations -> Environment I have set the following variables to reference the libraries.

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH = ${project_loc}/path/to/libs
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH = ${project_loc}/path/to/libs
```

And so far it all works. Now I have packaged my code and the existing native application as an Eclipse plugin. Whenever I try to run the code inside the plugin I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libsrcml.dylib
Referenced from: workspace/Project/src/nativeApp
Reason: image not found
```

To my understanding, this happens because the environment variables I had set previously reference {$project_loc}, which is the location where my Eclipse project was stored. Now, my code is no longer contained in that project, but it is contained inside a plugin, so the path for the variables no longer works. Question is, how can I set a path that references a folder inside my plugin? Alternatively, is it possible to, somehow, load those variables dynamically inside my Java code?

Comment: You probably need to look at using the 'Bundle-NativeCode' entry in the plugin MANIFEST.MF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [path variables](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcpathvars.htm) are used to specify a fixed location in the file system.

To identify a resource in a plugin, I would use its URL

**Case 1**: `Platform.getBundle("").getEntry("")`

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("your.bundle.id");
URL url = bundle.getEntry("yourDir/yourFile.txt");
File f = new File(FileLocator.resolve(url).toURI());
```

**Case 2** : Platform URL to your resource:

```
url = new URL("platform:/plugin/your.bundle.id/yourDir/yourFile.txt");
File f = new File(FileLocator.resolve(url).toURI());
```

Thanks to [Vogella](http://blog.vogella.com/2010/07/06/reading-resources-from-plugin/) for this tip.

**However,** for libraries in your plug-in it is a little bit different, as `System.loadLibrary("libname")` must be able to resolve your lib.

If you ship and use native libraries in your plug-in, please package your plugin as a directory, and not as a compressed jar file. 
So edit your plug-in's MANIFEST.MF and set your [Eclipse-BundleShape: dir](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fbundle_manifest.html)

```
Eclipse-BundleShape: dir
```

Then, your plug-in will be packaged as a folder, and then it is your responsibility to make your Native libraries interacting. Usually this depends on how the native libraries are linking each other, and on how your Java-to-native framework is setting the search paths.

**My simple solution,** is putting all the native libraries to the root folder of the Eclipse executable, which is the Java execution directory, so that I can get that path using the "user.dir" environment variable as follows:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Then, when all the natives are in the same folder, they can reference each other without problems.

*Please,* also check these resources:

- [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149818/how-do-i-tell-an-eclipse-plugin-where-a-native-library-resides-for-an-external-p)
- [this eclipse forum answer](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/165059/)

Comment: By looking at the resources you provided I managed to bundle the library in a way that `System.loadLibrary("libname")` manages to reference it.
However,  it seems that the native app still cannot find it since I get the error message `dyld: Library not loaded: libsrcml.dylib Reason: image not found`.
Can you clarify  what you mean with _the root folder of the Eclipse executable_ and how to reference the libs from there?

Comment: The root folder of the eclipse executable is the directory containing eclipse.exe. At development time, it is the folder containing your Eclipse IDE. But if you're building and shipping an Eclipse RCP product it is the folder containing your "product".exe file. Tell me if this is clear so I can update the response.

Comment: It is clear, but I would like to find a solution that also works when my plugin is used in a standard Eclipse installation.

Comment: The solution depends on how your native libraries reference each other. It is not an Eclipse problem, but it depends on which framework you use to access your libraries, and on how your native libraries are searching each other on the path. As already explained, the easy way is to put all the libraries in the root folder. Otherwise you will need to package your plugin with Bundle-Shape = dir, so the plug-in is open as a folder and not packaged; and then take care on how the libraries are linking each other.